# UNMET package dependencies babel - @babel\core\package.json missing

Tags: npm, npm-install, gulp-babel

I was trying to install gulp-babel with command `npm install gulp-babel` but after some process found below error :

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY  extraneous error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Zenverse\zenverse\node_modules\@babel\core\package.json
```

Full Logcat is as follows :

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY  extraneous error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\@babel\core\package.json
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY babel-core@^6.26.3
+-- gulp-babel@7.0.1
| +-- plugin-error@1.0.1
| `-- vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.2.1
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@2 || 3 || 4

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\@babel\core\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\@babel\helper-define-map\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\@babel\helper-module-imports\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\@babel\helper-module-transforms\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\@babel\plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\@babel\helper-simple-access\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\@babel\plugin-transform-block-scoping\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\@babel\plugin-transform-dotall-regex\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\@babel\plugin-transform-classes\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\@babel\plugin-transform-regenerator\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\@babel\plugin-transform-unicode-regex\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\@babel\template\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\@babel\traverse\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\chokidar\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\babel-register\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\output-file-sync\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\braces\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\extglob\package.json'
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-async-generators@7.0.0-beta.51 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@7.0.0-beta.51 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-catch-binding@7.0.0-beta.51 requires a peer of @babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN gulp-babel@7.0.1 requires a peer of babel-core@6 || 7 || ^7.0.0-alpha || ^7.0.0-beta || ^7.0.0-rc but none was installed.
npm WARN babel-loader@7.1.4 requires a peer of babel-core@6 but none was installed.
npm WARN babel-loader@7.1.4 requires a peer of webpack@2 || 3 || 4 but none was installed.
npm WARN zenverse@8.3.0 No repository field.
npm WARN zenverse@8.3.0 No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "gulp-babel"
npm ERR! node v4.4.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path \node_modules\babel-generator
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename '\node_modules\babel-generator' -> '\node_modules\.babel-generator.DELETE'
npm ERR!     at moveAway (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:38:5)
npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:27:7)
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename '\node_modules\babel-generator' -> '\node_modules\.babel-generator.DELETE'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename '\node_modules\babel-generator' -> '\node_modules\.babel-generator.DELETE'] parent: 'zenverse' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     \npm-debug.log
```

what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried running it in an admin command shell?

Comment: Yes. Tried. Above error code is in Administrator Node.js cmd

Comment: Maybe try cleaning the cache with `npm cache clean`

Comment: @S.Spieker I tried with cache clean but it still throwing `{ [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename '\node_modules\babel-generator' -> '\node_modules\.babel-generator.DELETE'] parent: 'zenverse' }` this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through the same issue and the solution for me was to update node to the latest version.

Please download the latest version of node from the below link:

https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: let me check with this too.